# How can I pause an event from flowing through an observable?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, kotlin

I am trying to create an Observable that can be paused in such a way that items stop being pushed through the observable until it becomes unpaused.

At which point, I'd like it to resume processing all of the unprocessed items.  My data source comes from outside the class, so what I have winds up looking like this:

```
class Agent {
    val publisher = PublishSubject.create<Event>()
    val subscription = createSubscription()

    fun trackEvent(e: Event) {
        publisher.onNext(e)
    }

    fun pause() {
        // ???
    }

    fun resume() {
        // ???
    }

    private fun createSubscription(): Subscription {
        return publisher
                .map { stringify(it) }
                .buffer(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 500) // capture 500 events or 10 seconds worth, whichever comes first.
                .map { /* create HttpPost request */ }
                .flatMap { /* send request to server */ }
                .subscribe { println("Received response: $it") }
    }
}
```

What I'm aiming for is that the `pause` function would stop the events from even going to the server (but would hold on to them until an eventual `resume`).  At the point `resume` happens, we'd send the events.  (Obviously we'd add in some extra help for back pressure in case we had *too many* events during the paused state.

I've tried various uses of buffering and windowing in order to make this work, but it never actually *pauses* the observable.  Instead, one of two things happens:

1. The event is dropped entirely (in the case of an unsubscribe, filter, etc.)
2. The event flows through as though nothing has happened.

Is there anything I can do to support this use case?  Or should I be writing this under the expectation that one of the above two outcomes is what will happen?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use another [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html) as a closing event for additional buffering:

```
val publisher = PublishSubject.create<Event>()
fun trackEvent(e: Event) {
    publisher.onNext(e)
    isPaused.onNext(isPaused.value)
}

val isActive = BehaviorSubject.create(true)
fun pause() {
    isActive.onNext(false)
}
fun resume() {
    isActive.onNext(true)
}

private fun createSubscription(): Subscription {
    return publisher
            .buffer(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 500) // -> Observable<List<Event>>
            .buffer({ isActive.filter { it } }) // -> Observable<List<List<Event>>>
            .flatMap { Observable.from(it) } // -> Observable<List<Event>>
            .map { /* create HttpPost request */ }
            .flatMap { /* send request to server */ }
            .subscribe { println("Received response: $it") }
}
```

The first `buffer` call will put incoming events into *buckets* with specified size or after time elapses. The second `buffer` will close current *bucket* on events emitted by observable indicating that the `Agent` is not paused (`isActive.filter { it }`). The `isActive` emits a value on every event and because the `isActive` is `BehaviorSubject` it will emit its last value to every new subscriber. That is on every *bucket* emitted by first `buffer` call it will either continue right away or wait until the `Agent` is resumed.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!  I'll give this a try tomorrow, but it definitely appears promising.

Comment: After testing this, it looks like `isActive` only emits `true` once (instead of on each buffer), until pause and unpause is called again.  This means that everything continues to buffer, and would be more akin to having a "drain" that only drains whenever I call resume.  It looks like based on what you're saying, I should have something that has an almost "constant" value being pushed through of "true" or "false" depending on what state it's in to make this work?

Comment: @ashays See the updated version, I missed adding the modified `trackEvent` method.